# Adding transparency to Graphics.Draw

Tags: c#

Is it possible to draw a Graphics in C# with a transparency e.g. 50%?

My actual code looks like this:

```
Image myBitmap = new Bitmap((int)sizeX,(int)sizeY);
Graphics myGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap);

Pen outerPenColor = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);

myGraphics.DrawRectangle(outerPenColor, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
```

this all works fine, but I want to have a transparent black, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Graphics` context and `Bitmap` objects supports transparency by default. The only thing you have to do is draw colors that are *not opaque*. There is an overload for the static method [`Color.FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9.aspx) that takes an *alpha value* and a color and returns a `Color` that has the transparency you specified. The alpha value is a value between 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque). For example:

```
// 75% opaque (25% transparent) Red
var semiRed = Color.FromArgb(191, Color.Red);
// 50% opaque (50% transparent) Black
var semiBlack = Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Black);
```

Now you can use that semi-transparent black as the color for your `Pen` and draw semi-transparent lines:

```
Pen outerPenColor = new Pen(semiBlack, 1);
myGraphics.DrawRectangle(outerPenColor, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Color.Black, use [Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromargb.aspx) which will allow you to specify an alpha value.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken (untested), it should work using a different Alpha on the pen, e.g.:

```
Pen outerPenColor = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(128,0,0,0), 1);
```